# Regularized linear regression model with Lp norm

Tags: machine-learning, regularization

Suppose we have a regularized linear regression model : $argmin_\theta ||y-X\theta||_2^2+\lambda ||\theta||_p^p$
For $p\geqslant 1$, I'm wondering what's the effect of increasing $p$ on bias and variance.
Did anyone see this before ?